# Be honest and potentially lose my job or lie and be safe?

Tags: software-industry, developer

I've been working for almost a half year at my current company (5 yoe). They talked about .Net Core / Microservices etc etc though in practice it seems I've been hired to follow up my current team mate.

The bad part is that my one and only team mate is very difficult to work with. The current project is his baby and a core product of our business. He is very harsh and closed minded about how to tackle solutions (his way or the high way). Furthermore the tech stack is ancient (vb.net winforms).

Since I had a thorough talk with my manager about what was promised and the misalignment with my current work he wanted to let me work partially in another team (up to date tech stack / webdevelopment).

The last couple of weeks I've been working fulltime at that other team and it was a breeze. Great team work and totally in line with my previous experiences / skillset and ambitions.

They had planned me fulltime because there was no work for me in my own team.

All good and well you might think until I had a meeting with my manager today. Basically he blamed me for not paying enough attention for my own team and I should have asked for knowledge session with my team mate? Sad part is I did ask my fellow team mate a couple of times were he has been working on and showed genuine interest, though only from my part as he was not very open for communication.

So logically I comitted to my work I've been doing at my new team.

Today he gave me a sort of ultimatum. I'll give my 100% at my current team or be honest that the new team is more to my liking and potentially lose my job, because the main reason I was hired is to follow up my teammate..

I guess I'll just be honest that I do like working with the new team since they like me working there and it has good team spirit, versus working in a small team with only one senior which takes on the role of gate keeper and is always negative about everything I do if it isn't done his way.

How would you approach this situation? Better be happy and potentially lose your job or be unhappy with job safety?

Comment: To be honest my personal wellbeing is more important. Furthermore the job market is great here and even better for developers. Though I am not a person of not trying. First I try to give it a chance before I jump ships. Though it seems at the moment I am past this station.

Comment: If (and pretty much only if) you have a choice between telling a lie and putting food on the table for your family, I suggest you lie. People that say "you should never lie" often haven't had the privilege of being long-term unemployed.

Comment: When you were hired, did the manager make it clear that you were hired to work with that "**team mate**" (using VB.NET) ? Or did he say that you were hire to work with the other technologies that you are comfortable with ?

Comment: @workharder, You commented that "**the job market is great here and even better for developers**". Then, why not looking for a new job that allow you to work with your favorite technologies ?

Comment: Because I first wanted to not give up and try to make the best of it. Furthermore they said both (working with the team mate) but also room to work with tech you're comfortable and good with (his boss). The job listing even mentioned .NET core, Saas, MVC, JS nothing about vb.net winforms development..

Comment: Ask your manager what is expected of your role. It sounds like the company needs the VB.NET program documented either for replacing it with a new program or replacing that programmer. Lying doesn't seem to be the real issue here.

Answer (score 2):

> I'll give my 100% at my current team or be honest that the new team is more to my liking and potentially lose my job,

This is what is called a **false dilemma**.

You should try as much as you can, to give 100% to whatever work you are assigned. I know sometimes this is hard.

Internally you can have whatever thoughts about the other team.

> Basically he blamed me for not paying enough attention for my own team and I should have asked for knowledge session with my team mate? Sad part is I did ask my fellow team mate a couple of times

Well, you should have explained this at the time. You should have rationalized your decision in terms of business value. You had one team that was very reluctant to work with you, and the other that was very ready to work with you.

Don't put it in terms of what was more fun.

---

Just on lying, I have a personal philosophy that if you want me to tell the truth, don't put ridiculous consequences on the "wrong" answer. If you don't have any right to an answer, and ALSO put ridiculous consequences on the "wrong" answer, you can almost expect a lie.

What I enjoy and don't enjoy is frankly none of my boss's business. If they threaten to fire me over having the wrong thought, you better believe I'm going to lie if I'm pressed to give my thoughts if they are not "correct".

Answer (score 0):

If the company does not seem to keep their word (what was promised to you), it is probably their company culture. Start looking for options and quit when you find something better.

Answer (score -1):

> Be honest .. or lie

Lying is never justified and about the worst thing you can do for your career and personal integrity. However in your case, you make this more dramatic than it needs to be.

> I guess I'll just be honest that I do like working with the new team since they like me working there and it has good team spirit, versus working in a small team with only one senior which takes on the role of gate keeper and is always negative about everything I do if it isn't done his way.

This is a good way to start the conversation. State the facts without judging, complaining, or blaming. If your manager is half way decent, they will engage in a discussion about how your current situation could be improved and maybe this will do something useful. A really good manager may also help you transfer to the new team, if there is no viable path to keep you long term happy.

It's also possible that your manager will dig in their feet and say "Well the job is what is is, take it or leave it". Then you have your answer and you know that this is not going to be sustainable for you in the long run. Start looking internally or externally.

It is unlikely they they would fire you on the spot.